# Note Frequency Program

Tags: c

Hello I'm trying to fix my note frequency program up. A user input is scanned, for example a#4, as note, flat or sharp or not, and octave and the program outputs the notes frequency. I used a4 as my base frequency. I thought I had it set up fine but when I input just a4 440 is not output as it should be. It may be a problem with the pow statements as I'm not very good at those yet. 
This was my reference equation:
 fn = f0 * (a)n 
where
f0 = the frequency of one fixed note which must be defined. A common choice is setting the A above middle C (A4) at f0 = 440 Hz.
n = the number of half steps away from the fixed note you are. If you are at a higher note, n is positive. If you are on a lower note, n is negative.
fn = the frequency of the note n half steps away.
a = (2)1/12 = the twelth root of 2 = the number which when multiplied by itself 12 times equals 2 = 1.059463094359...

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
int octave;
char letter, sharpFlat;

    printf("Enter the note letter in lower case, # if sharp, b if flat, space if none, and enter octave number: \n");
    scanf("%c%c%d",&letter, &sharpFlat, &octave);

    int semitones;
    int modifier;

    switch (letter)
{
        case 'c' :
        semitones = -9;
        break;

        case 'd' :
        semitones = -7;
        break;

        case 'e' :
        semitones = -5;
        break;

        case 'f' :
        semitones = -4;
        break;

        case 'g' :
        semitones = -2;
        break;

        case 'a' :
        semitones = 0;
        break;

        case 'b' :
        semitones = 2;
        break;

        default :
        semitones = 2;
        break;
}

    switch (sharpFlat)
{
        case '#' :
        modifier = 1;
        break;

        case 'b' :
        modifier = -1;
        break;

        case ' ' :
        modifier = 0;
        break;
}


semitones = semitones + sharpFlat;

float basefreq = 440.0;
float twelth = .083333;
float aa = pow(2, twelth);
float an = pow(aa, semitones);
float freq = basefreq * an; 




    printf("The frequency of the note is %f\n",freq);

return 0;   
}
```

Thank you and please bear with me I'm just learning programming lol.

Comment: I suppose you've meant `semitones = semitones + modifier;`

Comment: Wow such a simple solution. Thanks! Looks like it's fixed for the octave 4 but it's not returning the correct data for other octaves.

Comment: Note: Rather than `float twelth = .083333;` consider `float twelfth = 1.0/12.0;`.

Comment: Looks like I need to incorporate the octave into the equation now.

Comment: And a little math improvement: `pow(pow(a,b), c)` = `pow(a,b*c)` so you could skip `aa` and use `an = pow(2, semitones/12.0)`